# De purs miroirs?

Tags: articles

Baudelaire nous a donné:

> Car j’ai, pour fasciner ces dociles amants,
> De purs miroirs qui font toutes choses plus belles :
> Mes yeux, mes larges yeux aux clartés éternelles !

Pourquoi "De", et pas "Des"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a rule; "des" becomes "de" if there is an adjective before the noun.

> ([JM Kalmbach, grammaire pour l'étudiant finnophone](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/article-indefini.html#0481)) Règle générale
>
> Quand l’ar­ti­cle in­dé­fi­ni pluriel (pas singulier, ni massif) *des* dé­ter­mi­ne un grou­pe no­mi­nal contenant un ad­jectif an­té­po­sé (qui précède le nom), il prend la for­me *de*.
>
> - Il m’a offert **des** fleurs magnifiques    Il m’a offert **de** très belles fleurs.